# L298 works only when touched

Tags: l298n

The following image is my connection of l298 with Arduino.
[image]

This is the program.

```
int ENA = 10; // MCU PWM Pin 10 to ENA on L298n Board
int IN1 = 9;  // MCU Digital Pin 9 to IN1 on L298n Board 
int IN2 = 8;  // MCU Digital Pin 8 to IN2 on L298n Board

int ENB = 5;  // MCU PWM Pin 5 to ENB on L298n Board
int IN3 = 7;  // MCU Digital pin 7 to IN3 on L298n Board
int IN4 = 6;  // MCU Digital pin 6 to IN4 on L298n Board

void setup()
{

pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT); //Set all the L298n Pin to output
pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);
}
void DRIVEONE()
{
// Run the motors on both direction at fixed speed
digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH); // Turn HIGH motor A
digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
analogWrite(ENA, 200); // TO set the turning speed to 200 out of possible 
range 0 to 255

digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH); // turn HIGH motor B
digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);  // To set the turning speed to 200 out of possible 
range 0 to 255 
analogWrite(ENB, 200);
delay(2000);  // Delay to 2 seconds
void loop()
{
DRIVEONE(); 
delay(100);
}
```

The program seems to work fine but the motors run only when I touch all the 15 pins in L298 as shown in the second image.
I don't understand why the motors aren't running without touching those 15 pins.

[image]

I have connected the L298 to a 12V rechargeable battery and Arduino to a 9V battery.
Please help me understand what is wrong here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Your schematic does not show a connection from the ground line of the 12V battery to the GND connection on the Arduino.  This is required.